# Find and replace Date/Time within Text and make it Bold

Tags: php, regex

I have searched Stackoverflow for some answers to this and have tried numerous ways to make this work without success. So I was hoping some genius out there would be able to help me.

I am retrieving text from a database that has within it dates/times (`dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss`) within that text I would like to bold all instances where the regex finds a date in this format.

For example:

> 09/09/2013 16:42:01 Australia/West (Fake Name):
>
> 09/09/2013 15:44:01 (alert) alert stage 2
>
> 09/09/2013 15:38:55 Australia/West (Fake Name): 2 of the at Store have come back online.
>
> 09/09/2013 15:33:17 Australia/West (Fake Name): Store is having issues with their all 3. loading". Investigating.
>
> 09/09/2013 15:30:02 Australia/West (Fake Name):

would look something like this:

> **09/09/2013 16:42:01** Australia/West (Fake Name):
>
> **09/09/2013 15:44:01** (alert) alert stage 2
>
> **09/09/2013 15:38:55** Australia/West (Fake Name):
>   2 of the at Store have come back online.
>
> **09/09/2013 15:33:17** Australia/West (Fake Name): Store is having issues with their all 3. loading". Investigating.
>
> **09/09/2013 15:30:02** Australia/West (Fake Name):

I have used this regex for the date/time:

```
preg_match_all('/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/',$text,$matches);
```

with this code:

```
foreach ($matches as $res) 
{
    $replaceStr = "<strong>" . $res . "</strong>";
    str_replace($res, $replaceStr, $text);
}
```

but it seems to only find 1 match in the text so I need a little bit of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a `foreach` loop:

```
preg_replace('/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/m','<strong>$0</strong>', $text);
```

does all the matching and replacing at once.

Answer (score 0):

You should use modifier "m", so preg_match_all will now it works with multiline text:

```
$text = "09/09/2013 16:42:01 Australia/West (Fake Name):

09/09/2013 15:44:01 (alert) alert stage 2

09/09/2013 15:38:55 Australia/West (Fake Name): 2 of the at Store have come back online.

09/09/2013 15:33:17 Australia/West (Fake Name): Store is having issues with their all 3. loading\". Investigating.

09/09/2013 15:30:02 Australia/West (Fake Name):";

preg_match_all('/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/m',$text,$matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $res) 
  {
    $replaceStr = "<strong>" . $res . "</strong>";
    $text = str_replace($res, $replaceStr, $text);
  }

print $text;
```